# TIFF somewhat does not match with a shapefile

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, arcmap, shapefile, modis

Two layers, one .shp and a NDVI image (from the MODIS, exported it in TIFF format from envi), have the same geographic coordinate system (GCS_WGS_1984), but they are not overlapping 100% in ArcGIS. The data frame in WGS 84, UTM Zone 36 N. As you can see, these layers are shifted relative to each other (a little bit).

[image]

Comment: This looks like a typical spatial data registration issue.  The shapefile was generated from different data (some older imagery maybe).  You are trying to compare 'apples and oranges'.

Comment: Perhaps your vectordata is not WGS 84 but pulkovo, considering the town Dzhankoy is in Crimea.